# I can't find adb_usb.ini

Tags: android, root, kindle

I want to edit it so that it suits my Kindle Fire 6.2 firmware to be able to install apks from outside the market....

Why can't I find adb_usb.ini
I have installed Android SDK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated Android SDK platform tool and installed Google APIs by Google inc in Android SDK Manager. After it the file appeared

Comment: This works.  Strangely enough the usb package option has nothing to do with this file.

Comment: Worked for me!!